# problem with laravel: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, laravel

I have a discount block on my site. In the table with items there is a column `discount` and if it has a value `> 0`, then the block with discounts is displayed.
If there are no discounts, the discount block should not be displayed. And there is a problem with this. If there are no discounts, I get an error `Undefined offset: 0`.

My code:

```
$date = Carbon::today();
$count_discount = count(Item::where('discount', ">=", 1)->where('updated_at', '>=', $date)->get());
$item_bd = Item::where('discount', ">=", 1)->where('updated_at', '>=', $date)->orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(5)->get();
$classid = $item_bd[0]->classid;
$name = $item_bd[0]->market_hash_name;
$old_price = $item_bd[0]->price;
$discount = $item_bd[0]->discount;
$new_price = $item_bd[0]->price - (number_format($item_bd[0]->price / 100 * $discount, 2));
```

And in the blade i use:

```
@if ($count_discount === 0)
// no discount
@else
// block with dicsount
@endif
```

If there is a discount in the database, the discount block is displayed perfectly, if there are no discounts,
I get an error.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: no, it's not my answer

Comment: you can't access to index `0` if there is not an index `0`. Add a conditional before `$item_bd[0]....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty() in your blade. In your controller use this code

```
$count_discount = Item::where('discount', ">=", 1)->where('updated_at', '>=', $date)->get();
```

Then in your blade use:

```
@if(empty($count_discount))
Do something if no discount
@else
Do something with if discount is exist
@endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help :( if there are no discounts in the database, I continue to receive this error